# did you know where is a 'hello world ' of firefox extension demo 

Tags: javascript, firefox

i want to create a firefox extension 'hello world' demo  ,

what can i do  ?

thanks

Comment: I would urge you head over to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions and read the material. It's quite easy to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Getting_Started_with_Firefox_Extensions#The_Hello_World_Extension), its the official hello world example.

Answer (score 1):

This is the recommended place to start when building an extension (includes Hello World example):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension